# Avoid some result from filtering in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have applied AngualrJS filter on table row on one column name as "*Level of risk*". The filter is working fine but in my filtered data i want to show that row always which don't have value in column

"Level of risk" Working Example is at : In example, there is a row having value "Super Option" whose "Level of risk" is null. I want to show this row always. Any suggestions are highly appreciable.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vqo2uz6p/1/)

Comment: write a custom filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
$scope.riskFilter = function(value) {
            return value.investmentRisk === null || !$scope.search || value.investmentRisk === $scope.search.investmentRisk;
        }
```

and use it like

```
<tr ng-repeat="objInvData in filteredInvestmentData = (investmentData | filter:riskFilter )">
```